# Reentrance Lock Condition

Tags: java, multithreading, conditional-statements, reentrantlock

```
public class MyLockConditionTest {
    private final Lock alock = new ReentrantLock();
    private final Condition condition = alock.newCondition();
    private String message = null;

    public void waitForCallback() {
         alock.lock();
         try {
            // wait for callback from a remote server
            condition.await();
            doSomething(message);
         } finally {
              alock.unlock();
         }
    }

    // another thread will call this method as a callback to wake up the thread called condition.await()
    public void onCallbackReceived(String message) {
         alock.lock();
         try {
            this.message = message
            condition.signal();
         } finally {
              alock.unlock();
         }
    }
}
```

I have this code using ReentrantLock and Condition to implement a class to wait on certain callbacks from a remote server. I tested this code and seems working but I have a few questions.

1. Why do I need to do alock.lock() / unlock() in onCallbackReceived(). Without calling lock() / unlock(), I was getting an IllegalState exception. I am confused because the lock is held by the caller of waitForCallback() when onCallbackReceived() invoked by another thread so alock.lock() in onCallbackReceived() will always fail.
2. Do I need to wrap condition.await() in waitForCallback() with while loop?

   while(message==null) 
       condition.await();

Comment: 1) waiting for a condition requires a mutex to protect the condition from being changed in unsafe ways (visibility). 2) spurious wakeups amongst others, also https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarSignal for the exact same in low level

Answer (score 1):

> Why do I need to do alock.lock() / unlock() in onCallbackReceived(). Without calling lock() / unlock(), I was getting an IllegalState exception.

You are trying to `signal` a condition in which you do not own the lock.  The only way you would hold the lock is if `onCallbackReceived` is called from `doSomething` which there is no indication that is occurring.

> Do I need to wrap condition.await() in waitForCallback() with while loop?

Yes, imagine you have 5 threads stopped on the condition and 5 threads blocked on `lock`.  Only one thread can wake up.  What if when a waiting thread finally wakes up another thread had null'd that field out?  You will need to check again to ensure the predicate is still true.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. onCallbackReceived is not called from doSomething doSeomthing. There is another thread has a reference to this class object and the thread calls onCallbackReceived and that was what I don't understand. the lock is hold by the caller of waitForCallback but onCallbackReceived still can acquire lock and be able to reach signal()

Comment: So, you're saying both threads are holding the `lock` simultaneously?

Comment: authCallbackLock.isLocked() and  authCallbackLock.isHeldByCurrentThread() give me "false " in onCallbackReceived() right before alock.lock() although authCallbackLock.isLocked() is true after alock.lock() in waitForCallback()

Comment: Things will run really really really fast.  You shouldn't base success on timing of the `isLocked`.  You should have both threads `Thread.sleep(1000000L)` while holding the lock and right before the sleep write a debug.

Comment: If both aren't logged before going into the sleep than only one thread is succeeding.